# Unable to delete AWS VPC Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

One of my CloudFormation stacks is stuck in a `UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS` because I attempted to remove a subnet that was no longer needed. However, this subnet apparently has some resources attached to it, including an EC2 instance and a VPC Endpoint. I cannot delete this VPC Endpoint in AWS. When I attempt to delete the VPC Endpoint, I receive this error message:
[image]

How do I find out what dependencies this VPC Endpoint has and go about deleting it?

From what I can Google, `Operation is not allowed for requester-managed VPC endpoints for the service` means that AWS created this VPC endpoint for me, as part of a request for some resource. However, I have no idea which resource this VPC endpoint is tied to.

**Update:** the VPC Endpoint uses an ENI, but when I try to delete/detach this ENI, it says that the ENI is being used by a service and therefore cannot be deleted.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a requester managed VPC endpoint.

[Requester-managed network interfaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/requester-managed-eni.html)

> You cannot modify or detach a requester-managed network interface. If you delete the resource that the network interface represents, the AWS service detaches and deletes the network interface for you. To change the security groups for a requester-managed network interface, you might have to use the console or command line tools for that service.

You need to delete the resource which has created this vpc endpoint.

Comment: "You need to delete the resource which has created this vpc endpoint." - as I mentioned in my question, how do I go about figuring out which resource created this VPC endpoint? Is there any way via the console / CLI to find dependencies in AWS?

Comment: @YuChen as described in the documentation attached, check if there are any network interfaces or via cli <aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces>. Like in the api docs [CreateVpcEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateVpcEndpoint.html#API_CreateVpcEndpoint_SeeAlso) the sample response right above `see also`, you can see returned resources associated with the VPC endpoint.

Comment: Yes there is, but when I try to detach the ENI, it says that the "resource is being used by another service" and I cannot force detachment.

Comment: @YuChen as you have not created the ENI it is created by the service which you are using. You can figure out from the ENI  as it displays an alias or ID for the principal or service which service created this, and then track it down in your cloudformation template.

Comment: @samtodder, the description for that ENI says `VPC Endpoint Interface vpce-03bbee910c9512880`. That is the service which created the ENI. I am 100% certain I have no VPC Endpoint definitions in my CloudFormation template.

Comment: @YuChen which all resources you are dealing with in your cloudformation template ?. I already admitted that you are not creating the VPC endpoint, it is some service creating that for you. So is it possible for you share the template, I can replicate the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228596/discussion-between-samtoddler-and-yu-chen).

Answer (score 6):

Don't you have RDS Proxy? It creates VPC Endpoint on behalf of customer.

Comment: This is not related to RDS. There are many other AWS services that create VPC endpoints.

Comment: In my case, this was related to RDS. and there was no clue of why there was this endpoint in my VPC.

Comment: It was also related to RDS Proxy in my case.

Comment: serverless Redshift also creates VPC endpoint